# What can I use to test methods added to functions and methods added to the prototype?

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

**Question:** In the following code what can I use to see if I've added methods correctly or alternately what can I use to see how badly I screwed up?

In the following test code I add a method to a function and it works as expected.

```js
"use strict";

function aircraft() {
    return aircraft.myPlane();
}

aircraft.myPlane = () => 'XB-42';

console.log(aircraft());
```

In the next test code I add a method to the function's prototype and it also works as expected.

```js
"use strict";

function aircraft() {
    return aircraft.prototype.myPlane();
}

aircraft.prototype.myPlane = () => 'XB-42';

console.log(aircraft());
```

However in that last example I think I might have done something dumb but I'm not entirely sure.  Did that add the `.myplane()` function directly to the main Function prototype for all functions in the entire program?  Is there a way for me to check and see what I've actually done so I can test and compare my results?

Comment: Your second snippet with prototype makes very little sense: `prototype` is used when you create an instance of the constructor function. You don't have one. So it's no different to `aircraft.foo = { bar: () => 'XB-42' };` then `aircraft.foo.bar();`. To summarise: there is no difference at all, you assign a function to some object property then you invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *functions* and *classes* (that use the *function* keyword). In the first example, you're simply adding properties to the function, not to an instantiation of a class (which is probably what you were trying to do).

In a `function` constructor, you should reference that particular instantiation with `this`, like the following:

```js
function Aircraft() {
  // function constructor (doesn't do anything useful in either example)
}
const myAircraft = new Aircraft();
// assigns to this instantiation only:
myAircraft.myPlane = () => 'XB-42';
console.log(myAircraft.myPlane());
```

To assign to the prototype, do something like this:

```js
function Aircraft() {
// function constructor (doesn't do anything useful in either example)
}
// applies to all Aircraft:
Aircraft.prototype.myPlane = () => 'XB-42';
const myAircraft = new Aircraft();
console.log(myAircraft.myPlane());
```